# Prolog integer comparison

Tags: prolog, logic

Hi there I have a simple clock in Prolog which measures time in 5min intervals

```
nextTime(Hrs:Mins1, Hrs:Mins2) :- nextMins(Mins1, Mins2).
nextTime(Hrs1:'55', Hrs2:'00') :- nextHrs(Hrs1, Hrs2).

nextHrs('12', '13').
nextHrs('13', '14').
nextHrs('14', '15').
nextHrs('15', '16'). // and so on 

nextMins('00', '05').
nextMins('05', '10').
nextMins('10', '15').
nextMins('15', '20'). // and so on
```

Now I want to write a predicate which allows me to say whether time t2 is later or before time t1, it sound simple enough but I dont know how to compare two integers within a predicate.

I tried things liked:

```
after(H1:M1, H2:M2) :- (H1 < H2).
```

or

```
arithmetic(X,Y) :- (X<Y).
after(H1:M1, H2:M2) :- arithmetic(H1,H2).
```

Im really new to Prolog so above might seem silly to some.
So my actual question is how to compare two integers within a predicate definition in Prolog.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using strings for numbers instead of just numbers? If you use integers, the the solution shown by @CapelliC will work as desired.

Answer (score 2):

An useful Prolog feature it's '[Standard Order of Terms](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=standardorder)'. Then you could write

```
after(T1, T2) :- T1 @< T2.
```

Comment: This will work great as long as time is `HH:MM` where `HH` and `MM` are integers rather than strings. So `'3:30' @< '13:40'.` is false, but `3:30 @< 13:40.` is true.

Comment: @mbratch: maybe OP was already aware of the problem, since he posted atoms with leading zeroes...

Comment: Yes that's a good point. If leading zeroes are used in the string format then this will work just fine. That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any **integers**: you have *atoms*. The *atom* `'9'` compares are greater than than atom `12`.

So long as your atoms are always 2 decimal digits (`'09'` instead of `'9'`), you can use `compare/3`:

```
after(H1:M1,H2,M2) :- compare( '>' , H1:M1 , H2:M2 ) .

on_or_after(H1:M1,H2:M2) :- compare( '>' , H1:M1 , H2:M2 ) .
on_or_after(H1:M1,H2:M2) :- compare( '=' , H1:M1 , H2:M2 ) .
```

etc.

If you change your predicate to use *integers* instead of atoms

```
nextHrs(12, 13).
nextHrs(13, 14).
nextHrs(14, 15).
nextHrs(15, 16). // and so on  

nextMins(00, 05).
nextMins(05, 10).
nextMins(10, 15).
nextMins(15, 20). // and so on
```

you can use [arithmetic comparison operators](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=arithpreds) and simply write something like:

```
compare_time( H1:M1 , H2:M2 , '<' ) :- H1 < H2 .
compare_time( H1:M1 , H1,M2 , '<' ) :- M1 < M2 .
compare_time( HH:MM , HH:MM , '=' ) .
compare_time( H1:M1 , H2:M2 , '>' ) :- H1 > H2 .
compare_time( H1:M1 , H1:M2 , '>' ) :- M1 > M2 .
```

If you maintain your atoms consistently as 2-digit text values, you can still do the same thing, but you have to use [the standard order of terms operators](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=standardorder) instead of the arithmetic comparison operators.

```
compare_time( H1:M1 , H2:M2 , '<' ) :- H1 @< H2 .
compare_time( H1:M1 , H1,M2 , '<' ) :- M1 @< M2 .
compare_time( HH:MM , HH:MM , '=' ) .
compare_time( H1:M1 , H2:M2 , '>' ) :- H1 @> H2 .
compare_time( H1:M1 , H1:M2 , '>' ) :- M1 @> M2 .
```

Comment: If you are using `@<`, etc, as @CapelliC noted, you don't need to check hours and minutes separately since, if hours and minutes are integers, Prolog will do the "right" thing when you compare, for example, `3:25 @< 13:20` (it will be "true"). So your `compare_time(..., '<')` only needs to be one clause: `compare_time(T1, T2, '<') :- T1 @< T2`. But then the predicate is superfluous at that point.

Comment: Nicholas, as an addendum to my statement, the OP can use strings for hours and minutes and then use `T1 @< T2` as long as the hours and minutes are left-zero padded to two digits always (which I'm sure was their intention). The comparison, `'03':'25' @< '13':'20'` will "do the right thing".